# Is apprtc free for use?

Tags: android, webrtc

i am working on android application that use webrtc and i am using appRtcDemo on github [AppRTCDemo](https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo)

but this project use appr.tc server and i think it belong to google. 
so my question is it free to use or not and if it is not free is there a way to make my own server and how ?

Comment: There is no license, so it is copyrighted work.

Comment: that mean that i can't use it for my android app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

appr.tc is hosted by google on google cloud, just for the WebRTC sample demo.

[AppRTC demo](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc) server code is also open source, so you can setup your own.